# How to -force_load MoPub and all its files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, linker-errors, mopub

I'm trying to use **MoPub**. Similar to **admobs**, **MoPub** asks you to use the linker flag "-ObjC", however, this broke my code when I tried using it with **admobs** (I think it had something to do with Box2D).

Anyways, I got around this by doing a `-force_load` on the `.a` library file for admobs. MoPub, on the other hand, is not neatly packaged in a single .a library file. Does anyone know how I can either:

1. use -force_load on the mopub folder somehow, which is full of tons
   of    files
2. find and/or make a static library version of the MoPub SDK (I
   actually already attempted to make one, but couldn't figure out how
   to properly turn off ARC. Adding the .m's to source code and
   flagging them with -fno-objc-arc gave me an error because the
   compiler said "no file or directory found for "-fno-objc-arc")
3. Some other solution you've come across

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, so I ended up making a static library of all MoPub files. Here are the steps I took:

- create new IOS Project -> Cocoa Touch Static Library
- add all MoPub sources (I used their latest SDK, which is 3.2.0)
- mark all sources as ARC as per MoPub integration instructions

In the application project:

- added the library as a subproject
- in Build Phases -> Target Dependencies added the library as dependency
- added libMopubSDK.a in "Link binary with libraries"
- dragged the MoPub resource files to the application project (don't check "copy files..." - you want to reference the original resources)
- as my project doesn't build with -ObjC flag, to avoid a MoPub crash, I added

  $OTHER_LDFLAGS) -force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libMopubSDK.a

to the application projects' Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags.